# Remove duplicates but leave null fields

Tags: mysql

I allready found part of the solution in the following thread:

[Removing duplicate email address based on the lowest id in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8680477/removing-duplicate-email-address-based-on-the-lowest-id-in-mysql)

I have this MYSQL table that contains also email addresses from which i want the duplicates to be removed witch leaving the duplicate with the highest ID intact.
There are also many empty email-fields that should be ignored and thus preserved.
After that no duplicate entries should ever be allowed for the emailfield in the future.

How can i achieve this? My head is absolutely spinning over this and i can'figure it out.
I want to do this from within phpmyadmin since it should be a onetime operation only.

Coming from the following link: [MySQL remove duplicates from big database quick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1651999/mysql-remove-duplicates-from-big-database-quick)

I tried:

```
create table tmp like yourtable;

alter table tmp add unique (text1, text2);

insert into tmp select * from yourtable 
on duplicate key update text3=ifnull(text3, values(text3));

rename table yourtable to deleteme, tmp to yourtable;

drop table deleteme;
```

But that gave me a syntax error concerning the select * statement (3rd line).

Comment: Please provide the sql which you have tried.

Answer (score 1):

Try :

```
insert into tmp (email) select X.email from ((SELECT email FROM yourtable WHERE LENGTH(email) = 0) UNION (SELECT email FROM yourtable WHERE LENGTH(email) > 0 GROUP BY email ORDER BY id DESC)) AS X;
```

Comment: Tried it but adds only the records that actually hold an emailvalue. The records with empty email-fields are not inserted.

Comment: Nope, still the same result.